# How can I deal with slow performance on Contains query in Entity Framework / MS-SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I'm building a proof of concept data analysis app, using C# & Entity Framework. Part of this app is calculating TF*IDF scores, which means getting a count of documents that contain every word.

I have a SQL query (to a remote database with about 2,000 rows) wrapped in a foreach loop:

```
idf = db.globalsets.Count(t => t.text.Contains("myword"));
```

Depending on my dataset, this loop would run 50-1,000+ times for a single report. On a sample set where it only has to run about 50 times, it takes nearly a minute, so about 1 second per query. So I'll need much faster performance to continue.

Is 1 second per query slow for an MSSQL contains query on a remote machine?

What paths could be used to dramatically improve that? Should I look at upgrading the web host the database is on? Running the queries async? Running the queries ahead of time and storing the result in a table (I'm assuming a WHERE = query would be much faster than a CONTAINS query?)

Comment: Contains is the same as `LIKE '%word%'` and that search cant use index so will be slow because need do a full scan of your table everytime. You need to use [**FullText Search**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search)

Comment: or show us what you want to do. chances are that you can do that whole loop in one query

Comment: @Steve I've split a document into individual words, and need to get the inverse document frequency for each word (how many documents out of my entire database contain the word.) So a 1,000 word document has maybe 200 unique words, and I'm querying the database for each one to determine how many other documents contain that word.

Comment: so you store the entire document in one column in the db and you have multiple rows of document in one table? an example would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do much better than full text search in this case, by making use of your local machine to store the idf scores, and writing back to the database once the calculation is complete. There aren't enough words in all the languages of the world for you to run out of RAM:

1. Create a dictionary Dictionary<string,int> documentFrequency
2. Load each document in the database in turn, and split into words, then apply stemming. Then, for each distinct stem in the document, add 1 to the value in the documentFrequency dictionary.
3. Once all documents are processed this way, write the document frequencies back to the database.
4. Calculating a tf-idf for a given term in a given document can now be done just by:
5. Loading the document.
6. Counting the number of instances of the term.
7. Loading the correct idf score from the idf table in the database.
8. Doing the tf-idf calculation.

This should be thousands of times faster than your original, and hundreds of times faster than full-text-search.

Comment: This was helpful. So far I have implemented multiple tactics - full text index, storing idf values in a table, using multi-threaded code, and moving idf values to local memory from the database before querying them. All together, I'm seeing much faster performance.

Answer (score 1):

As others have recommended, I think you should implement that query on the db side. Take a look at [this article](https://csharpvault.com/blog/sql-server-full-text-search/) about **SQL Server Full Text Search**, that should be the way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. So far I have implemented multiple of the suggested tactics - full text index, storing idf values in a table, using multi-threaded code, and moving idf values to local memory from the database before querying them. All combine to equal much faster performance.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a `contains` query in a loop extremely bad idea. It kills the performance and database. You should change your approach and I strongly suggest you to create `Full Text Search` indexes and perform query over it. You can retrieve the matched record texts with your query strings.

```
select t.Id, t.SampleColumn from containstable(Student,SampleColumn,'word or sampleword') C 
inner join table1 t ON C.[KEY] = t.Id
```

Perform just one query, put the desired words which are searched by using operators (or, and etc.) and retrieve the matched texts. Then you can calculate TF-IDF scores in memory.

Also, still retrieving the texts from SQL Server into in memory might takes long to stream but it is the best option instead of apply N `contains` query in the loop.